# Blender 2.8 - I am only able to select the parent (first added) bone of an armature when using the cursor

Tags: armature, bones

**Situation**

I am using Blender 2.8 Beta on a Mac. Edit: It also happens in Windows

I have created a simple mesh then added an armature. Having added the first bone, I created 5 more by extruding each one from the previous. I then parented the mesh to the armature using automatic weighting.

**Problem**

Regardless of which mode I am in (object, edit, pose) I am only able to select the first bone that I added **using the cursor** (I am able to select them in the outliner). Looking at the outliner, it would appear that all the subsequent bones are children of that bone, so it seems I can only select the parent.

I have checked that they are all `selectable` in the outliner and they all should be.

Is this expected behaviour? All of the tutorials I have watched suggest that you should be able to select individual bones in both edit and pose modes.

Have I done something wrong or is there a setting that I'm unaware of? Its very frustrating to have to use the editor to select individual bones.

[Here is the .blend file](https://cdn.glitch.com/1b18eb7b-5657-451e-bf06-770c6b394832%2Fbones_test.blend?1558949314409)

Thanks for any advice - any more info needed please let me know.

I have the same problem, but only in my computer, if I change to my laptop everything works as it should (with the same armature).

Comment: could you please share your file or at least the armature?

Comment: Hi @moonboots thanks for your reply, here is an example file https://cdn.glitch.com/1b18eb7b-5657-451e-bf06-770c6b394832%2Fbones_test.blend?1558949314409 very grateful for any advice

Comment: it works normal with my 2.8 version, so I'm not sure what's your problem  :/

Comment: same problem here. To select a bone other than the first, each click on that first bone select other bones in order. Or select with the circle select tool.

Comment: Problem solved in last update (May 28, v2.80.72)